# How to implement RAID 6 over different nodes on the network

Tags: lvm, software-raid

I am trying to create a RAID 6 over independent nodes which are on the network. I have to further implement LVM over this RAID 6. I read about it at http://www.mylinuxplace.com/building-raid-over-network-share/ . I am not so clear with the concept of smb, samba and loop devices:

- What is the difference between NAS and smb?
- Is creating a loop device necessary if I am using block devices/nodes which have VMs?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist, but wondering RAID over ethernet myself, I can give you my experience.
LVM over RAID, is well documented on the web, as you don't have any question, I don't expand on this topic

difference between NAS ans Smb (CIFS), the difference is like difference between bottle and wine:
NAS : Network Attached Storage (a Storage device linked to a network)
basicaly it is a server providing some services;
very roughly, services can be SMB/CIFS (windows share), NFS (linux share) or AFP (apple share)
**the short answer is "One NAS device can provide a sharing service based on SMB protocol"**

"necessity of loop device" : you can create any software RAID (mdadm) with any devices (storage device at least), including hard disk, logical partition from LVM, usb stick, network disk.
Be sure to understand that the shared file node1.img (from your link) is a file not a device. As this file is used as a container that's why you NEED to create the loop device.

**Short answer : when creating an encrypted "home directory" mount can manage container (using the loop option)
RAID-software can only manage devices (not file or container) that's why the device loop is required.**

Your conclusion will be LVM over RAID6, but your main project is RAID over network. The solution of your link is
cluster 1:device(HD)->filesystem->file->software(NFS or SMB)--->-(network)->---[master]:software(NFS or SMB)->device loop->software-raid (then using your raid array)

I tried a low layer sharing solution with open-iscsi:
Once again, my experience with RAID include RAID with USB-drive (I am not proud of this one) and RAID over network (not satisfied with this one)
If I do understand your project, you have at least 4 machines on your network:
 - you do have at least 4 cluster providing "free space" (for RAID6)
 - you do have "1 master" 
The solution I experienced was using a low layer sharing solution:

- "sharing a device on each cluster" through an iSCSI-target : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ISCSI_Target
- "accessing all the shared devices" through an iSCSI-initiator, this creates a device on the master (you can access the network disk like if it was local, including create partition): https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ISCSI_Initiator
- on the Initiator machine, I created my RAID array, then do everything I wanted on it; including LVM, shares, etc...

PROs of iSCSI:

- it allow RAID over network
- iSCSI allow short network shutdown

CONs of iSCSI:

- iSCSI can be accessed by only ONE initiator at a time, high-availability with pacemaker was quite tough,
- iSCSI is not hard, but not easy to setup,
- you know what RAID is? when one device of the RAID array is off, it becomes 'faulty', this means when one cluster is off (for example reboot or disconnected), the RAID array becomes 'degraded'; thus you need to remove you faulty device, close the iSCSI instance, reinitiate your iSCSI instance, readd your device et re-sync you RAID array,
- poor performance : network 10/100/1000 is the limit of the read/write access to the RAID... it is a low limit (I don't have published my test, but the network-switch is the narrow point),

This was "the SAN of the poor" for the 4 clusters, the NAS (with RAID/LVM/Share) for the master.
I used this solution for about 1 year, until I decided to put the 4 disks into one computer.

To my experience, iSCSI is more efficient than NFS (and much more than SMB/CIFS), the main issue is not how to share storage capacity, but how to manage hardware failure (computer reboot, hard-disk failure, network failure).

PS : I tried other low layer solution like vblade with VERY poor performance.
PPS : I am currently looking MooseFS  www.moosefs.org/about-mfs.html
MooseFS is a bit under RAID5 (in term of available space), but manage very well hardware failure.